# Run Subreport On-Demand in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table report with a parent row containing data, and a child row which is a subreport, a graph of data from the parent row. The visibility of the subreport is toggled by clicking the first column of the parent row. It works pretty well, but for certain parameter sets, the table will have ~10,000 rows, and it has to render all subreports at runtime, which is very slow.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to only run the subreports on-demand when the toggling item is clicked? I know I can open the subreport in another window on-demand to avoid this but I would prefer to keep these on the same screen for ease-of-access.

Thanks friends!

Comment: one way to do this is to use a hidden parameter.. lets call it hide.. and set it's default to 0. Pass that to the subreport and say where @hide<>0. when the use clicks the toggle item, you will need to refresh the report and set hide = 1 which will render the subreports..

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: You can also use the `Scope()` function and check if you inside the toggled item or not. Based on the `true or false` output you can wrap a `IIF()` around your subreport action.